# CSS responsive 2 column layout item ordering issue

Tags: css

I have this:

```
<style>
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
  width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <p>Item 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
  <p>Item 3</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <p>Item 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>Item 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The correct order is column 1 from top to bottom then column 2 from top to bottom, it's fine on desktop but on mobile it stacks them

1
3
2
4

How can I get them in the right order on mobile?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like this could be solved perfectly with css grids.
This allows you to mix and position it ay way you want. Using flexbox would also be an option.  Or you could change your HTML to have columns devided into rows instead of the other way around. If you place the 2 columns underneath each other, you'll have the same result.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "one three"
    "two four";
}

.container div:nth-child(1) { grid-area: one; }
.container div:nth-child(2) { grid-area: two; }
.container div:nth-child(3) { grid-area: three; }
.container div:nth-child(4) { grid-area: four; }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "one"
      "two"
      "three"
      "four";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div>Item 1</div>
   <div>Item 2</div>
   <div>Item 3</div>
   <div>Item 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to reorder them for mobile would be to use flexbox and its order property. With a media query made for mobile phones you can control the order but it will require you to use flex instead of floats.

Answer (score 0):

By using order we can achieve.

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .second-column {
    order: 1;
  }

  .third-column {
    order: 0;
 }
  .fourth-column {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column first-column">
    <p>Item 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column second-column">
  <p>Item 3</p>
  </div>
<div></div>
  <div class="column third-column">
    <p>Item 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column fourth-column">
    <p>Item 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the grid if you want by implementing the following:

HTML

```
  <div class="row">

   <div class="column1">
    <p>Item 1</p>
   </div>
   <div class="column2">
     <p>Item 3</p>
   </div>
   <div class="column3">
    <p>Item 2</p>
   </div>
   <div class="column4">
    <p>Item 4</p>
   </div>

 </div>
```

CSS

```
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing:inherit;
 }

 html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size:62.5%;
 }

.row {
  width: 114rem;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(min-content,20rem))

  }

 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column1 {
    grid-row:1/1;
   }
   .column2 {
     grid-row:3/4;
    }
   .column3 {
    grid-row:2/3;
   }
   .column4 {
    grid-row:4/5;
   }
 }
```

codepen https://codepen.io/ahamdan/pen/oNLbqvO